# Finetune PyTorch model after training fc layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to do Transfer Learning using PyTorch. I wan to train fc layers first and then to finetune the whole network. Unfortunately after training fc layers and then passing my network to finetune, I am losing the accuracy that was acquired in the first training. Is this an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong here?

Here is the code:

```py
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 4)
model = model.to(device)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

model = trainer.fit_model(dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=10)
# fit model is basic PyTorch training function found here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#convnet-as-fixed-feature-extractor The only difference is that scheduler is an optional param.

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)

# Here I am finetuning the model
model_ft = trainer.fit_model(
    dataloader, model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler=exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=10
)
```

Am I missing something here or should I just train the model once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is something that can happen when performing transfer learning called 
 **catastrophic forgetting**. Basically, you update your pretrained weights too much and you 'forget' what was previously learned. This can happen notably if your learning rate is too high. I would suggest trying at first a lower learning rate, or using diffentiable learning rate (different learning rate for the head of the network and the pretrained part, so that you can have a higher learning rate on the fc layers than for the rest of the network).